# How to remove the blank JFrame from appearing?

Tags: java

When I run my java program, two JFrames are showing, the JFrame that I created and another one that is blank that I cannot close. I think this error also has something to do with my JFrame that I created with components in it, not show when I run the program, instead the one showing is the blank JFrame. How do I fix this?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;

public class trial extends Frame implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame;
    JButton newButton1, newButton2, newButton3,newButton4,newButton5,newButton6,newButton7,newButton8,newButton9; 
    Icon ic1=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A1.png");
    Icon ic2=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A2.png");
    Icon ic3=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A3.png");
    Icon ic4=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A4.png");
    Icon ic5=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A5.png");
    Icon ic6=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A6.png");
    Icon ic7=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A7.png");
    Icon ic8=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A8.png");
    Icon pink=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\DB\\Desktop\\eclipse\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\c9.png");
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    trial window = new trial();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public trial() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 986, 677);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        newButton1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A1.png"));
        newButton1.setBounds(43, 37, 150, 150);

        newButton2 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A2.png"));
        newButton2.setBounds(191,37, 150, 150);

        newButton3 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A3.png"));
        newButton3.setBounds(340,37, 150, 150);

        newButton4 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A4.png"));
        newButton4.setBounds(43,186, 150, 150); 

        newButton5 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A5.png"));
        newButton5.setBounds(191,186, 150, 150);

        newButton6 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A6.png"));
        newButton6.setBounds(340,186, 150, 150);

        newButton7 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A7.png"));
        newButton7.setBounds(43,335, 150, 150);

        newButton8 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\A8.png"));
        newButton8.setBounds(191,335,150, 150);

        newButton9 = new JButton(pink);
        newButton9.setBounds(340,335,150, 150);


        newButton1.addActionListener(this); 
        newButton2.addActionListener(this);  
        newButton3.addActionListener(this);  
        newButton4.addActionListener(this);  
        newButton5.addActionListener(this);  
        newButton6.addActionListener(this);  
        newButton7.addActionListener(this);  
        newButton8.addActionListener(this);  
        newButton9.addActionListener(this);

        frame.getContentPane().add(newButton1);frame.getContentPane().add(newButton2);frame.getContentPane().add(newButton3);frame.getContentPane().add(newButton4);frame.getContentPane().add(newButton5);frame.getContentPane().add(newButton6);
        frame.getContentPane().add(newButton7);frame.getContentPane().add(newButton8);frame.getContentPane().add(newButton9);
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        dispose();
        DrumInfo a = new DrumInfo();
        a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        a.setVisible(true);

    }
});
btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jaxma\\Documents\\JAVA\\Final Project\\img\\INSTRUMENTS\\drums.png"));
btnNewButton.setBounds(597, 37, 300, 277);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Click the picture to find out what's the picture about!");
lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Berlin Sans FB Demi", Font.PLAIN, 15));
lblNewLabel.setBounds(563, 315, 382, 45);
frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("BACK");
btnNewButton_1.setBounds(412, 563, 156, 63);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
JButton btnCategories = new JButton("CATEGORIES");
btnCategories.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        dispose();
        Puzzle2 a = new Puzzle2();
        a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        a.setVisible(true);

    }
});
btnCategories.setBounds(604, 563, 156, 63);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnCategories);
JButton btnNext = new JButton("NEXT");
btnNext.setBounds(789, 563, 156, 63);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnNext);

        setSize(600,500);  
        setLayout(null);  
        setVisible(true);  


    }  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton1){  
            Icon s1 = newButton1.getIcon();
            if(newButton2.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton2.setIcon(s1);
                newButton1.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton4.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton4.setIcon(s1);
                newButton1.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton2){  
            Icon s1 = newButton2.getIcon();
            if(newButton1.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton1.setIcon(s1);
                newButton2.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton3.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton3.setIcon(s1);
                newButton2.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton5.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton5.setIcon(s1);
                newButton2.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton3){  
            Icon s1 = newButton3.getIcon();
            if(newButton2.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton2.setIcon(s1);
                newButton3.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton6.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton6.setIcon(s1);
                newButton3.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton4){  
            Icon s1 = newButton4.getIcon();
            if(newButton1.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton1.setIcon(s1);
                newButton4.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton7.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton7.setIcon(s1);
                newButton4.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton5.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton5.setIcon(s1);
                newButton4.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton5){  
            Icon s1 = newButton5.getIcon();
            if(newButton2.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton2.setIcon(s1);
                newButton5.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton6.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton6.setIcon(s1);
                newButton5.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton4.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton4.setIcon(s1);
                newButton5.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton8.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton8.setIcon(s1);
                newButton5.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton6){  
            Icon s1 = newButton6.getIcon();
            if(newButton9.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton9.setIcon(s1);
                newButton6.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton3.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton3.setIcon(s1);
                newButton6.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton5.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton5.setIcon(s1);
                newButton6.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton7){  
            Icon s1 = newButton7.getIcon();
            if(newButton4.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton4.setIcon(s1);
                newButton7.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton8.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton8.setIcon(s1);
                newButton7.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource()==newButton8){  
            Icon s1 = newButton8.getIcon();
            if(newButton9.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton9.setIcon(s1);
                newButton8.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton7.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton7.setIcon(s1);
                newButton8.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton5.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton5.setIcon(s1);
                newButton8.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }  
        if(e.getSource()==newButton9){  
            Icon s1 = newButton9.getIcon();
            if(newButton6.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton6.setIcon(s1);
                newButton9.setIcon(pink);
            }
            if(newButton8.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
                newButton8.setIcon(s1);
                newButton9.setIcon(pink);
            }

        }
        if(newButton1.getIcon().equals(ic1)&&newButton2.getIcon().equals(ic2)&&newButton3.getIcon().equals(ic3)&&newButton4.getIcon().equals(ic4)&&newButton5.getIcon().equals(ic5)&&newButton6.getIcon().equals(ic6)&&newButton7.getIcon().equals(ic7)&&newButton8.getIcon().equals(ic8)&&newButton9.getIcon().equals(pink)) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations! You won.");    
        }


    }  
}
```

Comment: It creates an error. 

The method dispose() is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}
 The method dispose() is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}
 The method setSize(int, int) is undefined for the type trial
 The method setLayout(null) is undefined for the type trial
 The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type trial

Comment: that's because you have to call dispose on a (J)Frame. call it on the one you have. It doesn't create an error, you are mixing two frames, that is what's leading you into trouble

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? I'm a beginner here in java and I really don't know what to do.